# systemSoundID crashes my iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, sigkill

```
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           pathForResource:@"deathsc" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge  CFURLRef)
                                     [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], & soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
```

Whenever I run this bit of code on the simulator, it works perfectly (and sounds terrifying), but when I run it on my iPad, the game freezes and if I touch the screen, I get a sigkill error

Comment: check for the soundFile :: use assert(soundFile) on the device!

Comment: and check for the return code of AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID. save it and assert(retVal == 0 /* or what success is these days */) :D (also try on device!)

Comment: adding assert seemed to make it work, but now the sound stutters at the end

Comment: Well it only works half the time